# how scanf works if character is given as input in place of integer

Tags: c

```
do
{
    printf("minutes: ");
    scanf("%d", &minutes);
}while(minutes < 1);
```

For above code if minutes is given some character then minutes has the value "2".
If some negative integer given as input first then a character, the statement "minutes: " repeats for infinite times.

I ran this program in codeblocks. Why it is happening?

Answer (score 4):

`scanf("%d",&minutes)` will not read the value of the character. The value in `minutes` will be unchanged. The character will remain in the buffer and scanf will keep trying to read it and keep failing.

The return value of `scanf` will be the number of elements read, so it will be 0 if you feed in a character, and that can be used to break the loop.

```
do
{
  printf("minutes: ");
  ret = scanf("%d", &minutes);
  if (ret != 1)
     break;
}while(minutes < 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns `0` in this case. The `scanf()` function returns the number of matched format specifiers. In this case, none matched and hence it returns `0`.

If you initialize `number` before calling `scanf()` and it then fails returning `0`, the value you used to initialize `number` doesn't change after the call to `scanf()`.

If you don't initialize `number`, then trying to read the value is *undefined behavior*. It will have an undeterminate value so you can't predict which value it will be.

Comment: The weakness to attempting to use the prior value of `number` occurs when `scanf()` returns `EOF` due to a rare input error.  The state of `number` is not defined.  Better to use the return value of `scanf()` and friends to steer logic and not the prior value.